# Simple Factorial Finder function

Tags: c++

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorialFinder(int x){
    if (x==1){
        return 1;
        }else{
            return x*factorialFinder(x-1);
            }
    }

int main()
{
 cout << factorialFinder(5) << endl;
}
```

I have currently hard time to exactly understand how the programs makes 5*4*3*2*1 = 120

For me if we take each line of the program it would do :

```
5*factorialFinder(5-1) is 5*4       
4*factorialFinder(4-1) is 4*3       
3*factorialFinder(3-1) is 3*2       
2*factorialFinder(2-1) is 2*1        
so 5*4*4*3*3*2*2*1 = 2880
```

Sorry I feel dumb, I tried to wait some days and think again about it.
I'm begginer in c++.
Does it has anything to do with callstack ?

Like i was thinking about this also :

Original function make :

```
5*4 = 20 20 is the returned value       
4*3 = 12 12 is the returned value        
3*2 = 6 6 is the returned value     
2*1 = 2 2 is the returned value    
1*1 = 1 STOP BECAUSE x == 1
```

call stack pop off

```
1*1=1 1 is the returned value       
2*1=2 2 is the returned value        
3*2=6 6 is the returned value     
4*6=24 24 is the returned value     
5*24=120 120 is the returned value
```

I would be glad if someone can explain me exactly what does the function exactly line by line...

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: "`5*factorialFinder(5-1)` is 5*4" no it isn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so what does it do ?

Comment: @K.Doo How do you think `5*4!` is equal to `5*4`??

Comment: `fact(n) = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1`, this is what your program does, execute it a debugger or add prints if you have a doubt

Comment: 5*4 = 5*4 = 20 ?

Comment: @bruno Thank you bruno i'll try it out

Comment: @K.Doo look at my answer, I just print rather than compute, but that does he same

Comment: Instead of "_`5*factorialFinder(5-1) is 5*4`_", a correct depiction would be "__`5*factorialFinder(5-1) is 5*4*factorialFinder(4-1)`__".

Comment: The thing about recursion is that you don't have to think about it, especially not 'line by line'. It just works. Function `a` calling function `b` just works, why shouldn't function `f` calling function `f`, what's the difference?

Comment: @john not sure if I am misunderstanding completely, but writing code in the spirit of "it just works" is a terrible idea

Comment: Alright thank you all for your explanation, i hope i won't have to deal much with recursive function, it gives me headache

Comment: I don't see any good reason to use recursion, you say you don't like it so... do that with a for loop! Simplifying the problem is the first step to take imho, so no recursion and no backward counts when it's not needed, just loop from 1 to x: int result = 1; for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++ ) result *= i; return result;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just printing rather than compute, using an equivalent definition :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void factorialFinder(int x){
    if (x==1){
      cout << 1;
    } else {
      factorialFinder(x-1);
      cout << " * " << x;
    }
}

int main()
{
  factorialFinder(5);
  cout << endl;
}
```

Execution :

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void factorialFinder(int x){
    if (x==1){
      cout << 1;
    } else {
      cout << x << " * ";
      factorialFinder(x-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
  factorialFinder(5);
  cout << endl;
}
```

Execution :

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Or if you prefer to see all :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorialFinder(int x) {
  cout << "fact(" << x << ") = ";
  if (x==1){
    cout << 1;
    return 1;
  } else {
    cout << x << " * (";

    int v = factorialFinder(x-1);

    cout << ") = " << x << "*" << v << " = " << x*v;
    return x*v;
  }
}

int main()
{
  factorialFinder(5);
  cout << endl;
}
```

Execution :

```
fact(5) = 5 * (fact(4) = 4 * (fact(3) = 3 * (fact(2) = 2 * (fact(1) = 1) = 2*1 = 2) = 3*2 = 6) = 4*6 = 24) = 5*24 = 120
```

Comment: for once i upvoted for not providing lots of explanation, sometimes one line of code explains more than lots of text.

Comment: Corollary: Never trust a comment.

Comment: C'est fait, merci encore Bruno :)

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is flawed.

```
5*factorialFinder(5-1) is 5*4
```

Not it is not. When you expand the function call you also have to do that recursively. The recursive rule is

```
factorialFinder(x) == x * factorialFinder(x-1)
```

Convince yourself that this is correct. Then apply it to your example:

```
5*factorialFinder(5-1) == 5* 4*factorialFinder(4-1)
                       == 5*4* 3*factorialFinder(3-1)
                       == 5*4*3* 2*factorialFinder(2-1)
                       == 5*4*3*2*1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that helped me a long time ago.

This is a traditional non-recursive factorial function

```
int trad_fact(int n)
{
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
         res *= n;
    return res;
}
```

Now here our first attempt to write a recusrive factorial function

```
int recur_fact(int n)
{
    return trad_fact(n);
}
```

Not very good, it's not even recursive, all it does is use the `trad_fact` function we've already written. But I hope you agree that it will give the right result (assuming `trad_fact` does).

Now lets make a special case out of `1`.

```
int recur_fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return trad_fact(n);
}
```

Not much better, we've still using `trad_fact` for every case except `1`, and still not recursive, but still returns the right result.

Here's another change, this time we've going to do the first multiplication in `recur_fact` but use `trad_fact` for the rest of the calculation

```
int recur_fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * trad_fact(n - 1);
}
```

Now `recur_fact` is doing a bit more work than previously, for instance `recur_fact(5) ==> 5 * trad_fact(4) ==> 5 * 24 ==> 120`, which is the right answer but there's still no recursion.

Now think about this. We have two functions `trad_fact` and `recur_fact`, both work out factorials, they do it in a different way, but given the same parameter both will return the same result. In other words the functions are equivalent. Now if they are equivalent then any place you see one function being used you can substitute the other function and the program won't change. And that applies even inside the `recur_fact` function! So we can do this

```
int recur_fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * recur_fact(n - 1);
}                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And as if by magic we've suddenly got a recursive function. And we've proved it's correct every step of the way!

Answer (score 0):

As everybody here says, why do you assume

`5*factorialFinder(5-1) is 5*4` beforehand

Recursion is a dynamic programming technique. So here, factorialFinder(4) method calls returned value will be substituted. Instead of just **5 * 4**, THe stack trace would reverse like this :

```
factorialFinder(5) = 5 * factorialFinder(5-1) = 5 * factorialFinder(4)
```

Now you need to find factorialFinder(4) :

```
factorialFinder(4) = 4 * factorialFinder(3)
factorialFinder(3) = 3 * factorialFinder(2)
factorialFinder(2) = 2 * factorialFinder(1)
factorialFinder(1) = 1
```

Now we got a value lets return to the called function which is factorialFinder(2)) :

```
factorialFinder(2) = 2 * factorialFinder(1) = 2*1 = 2
factorialFinder(2) = 2
```

So let's solve for factorialFinder(3) and so on:

```
factorialFinder(5) = 5 * factorialFinder(4)
factorialFinder(4) = 4 * factorialFinder(3)
factorialFinder(3) = 3 * 2 = 6
factorialFinder(2) = 2
```

Up one return :

```
factorialFinder(5) = 5 * factorialFinder(4)
factorialFinder(4) = 4 * 6 = 24
factorialFinder(3) = 6
factorialFinder(2) = 2
```

Substituting factorialFinder(4)=24 in the factorialFinder(5) solves the function:

```
factorialFinder(5) = 5 * 24 = 120
factorialFinder(4) = 24
factorialFinder(3) = 6
factorialFinder(2) = 2
```

> Now you have the result as `factorialFinder(5) = 120`

when doing recursion, remember you have to do reverse lookup only if you have a value instead of a function/equation.

Answer (score 0):

The key to recursion is understanding recursion. In this case, you know that 5! is

```
5*4*3*2*1
```

The recursion AHA! moment comes in noticing that this is the same as

```
5 * (4*3*2*1) = 5 * 4!
```

So then you can note that 4! = 4 * 3! and 3! = 3 * 2! and you can make the general formula

```
n! = n * (n-1)!
```

with a starting point of 1! defined to be 1

This general case is exactly modeled in your program.

```
return x*factorialFinder(x-1);
```

with the base case handled by

```
if (x==1) return 1;
```